# How to set a secondary control MaxWidth property to the same as another in a different container

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this `StackPanel` in one grid on my form:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="panelWeelyBibleReading" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="2">
    <Label>Bible Reading for Week:</Label>
    <TextBox x:Name="textWeeklyBibleReading">PSALMS 60-68</TextBox>
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Margin="2">
    <Label>Opening Song:</Label>
    <ComboBox x:Name="comboSongOpen" ItemsSource="{StaticResource SongTitles}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="local:SongTitleItem">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number, StringFormat='000 - '}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ComboBox.MaxWidth>
            <Binding Path="ActualWidth" 
                ElementName="textWeeklyBibleReading"/>
        </ComboBox.MaxWidth>
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Further down the form in a **different** grid I have this :

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Margin="2">
    <Label>Closing Song:</Label>
    <ComboBox x:Name="comboSongEnd" ItemsSource="{StaticResource SongTitles}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="local:SongTitleItem">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number, StringFormat='000 - '}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ComboBox.MaxWidth>
            <Binding Path="ActualWidth" 
                ElementName="panelWeeklyBibleReading.textWeeklyBibleReading"/>
        </ComboBox.MaxWidth>
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Initially I tried using the same `"textWeeklyBibleReading"` for the `MaxWidth` in the second combo. But it doesn't work. No warnings. Just doesn't work. So I thought about applying a name to the previous `StackPanel` in teh hopes I could use it as some kind of access point. But it still doesn't work.

So my problem is that I need to set the MaxWidth on the second combo, which is in a different grid, but using the value that was calculated on the first grid combo. Am I making sense?

I would show the complete form markup if it helps.

Comment: Use only `textWeeklyBibleReading` instead of `panelWeeklyBibleReading.textWeeklyBibleReading`.

Comment: try  <Binding Width,ElementName="textWeeklyBibleReading"/>

Comment: @tabby That is what the proposed answer suggests.

Comment: Oh yes I didn't saw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should edit to:

```
<ComboBox.MaxWidth>
   <Binding Path="Width" 
            ElementName="textWeeklyBibleReading"/>
</ComboBox.MaxWidth>
<Binding Path=Width, ElementName=textWeeklyBibleReading/>
```

cause there is no property such as `ActualWidth`, instead it should be `Width`. And there is no need to write container name `panelWeeklyBibleReading`, just write `ElementName` that you need.

**Update:**

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate DataType="local:SongTitleItem">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" MaxWidth="{Binding Path=Width, 
                                  ElementName=textWeeklyBibleReading}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number, StringFormat='000 - '}" />
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
    </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

You should set `MaxWidth` of `StackPanel` of `ComboBox` cause outer ``` StackPanel``(<StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Margin="2">) ``` which contains your `ComboBox` automatically sets `Width` to the outer `StackPanel` to your `ComboBox`. So I suggest to bind `Width` of your ComboBox to its `ItemTemplate`. Cause `ItemTemplate` has `Data/template`, then it is better to bind `Width` of `ComboBox` to `StackPanel` located into your `DataTemplate`.

Comment: Thanks. Will try. But it works for first combo, using ActualWidth. Why not second?

Comment: It is not working for this xaml: `<Binding Path="ActualWidth" 
                ElementName="panelWeeklyBibleReading.textWeeklyBibleReading"/>`?

Comment: Hhm. I had to remove the comma in yoru answer. But it does not seem to work. My combo still changes size as the items are picked.

Comment: That works great. Thanks! Could you please indicate in your answer **why** setting the value on the `StackPanel` was better than the `ComboBox`?